# Click detection issue with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, tic-tac-toe

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import K_DOWN
import time
from time import sleep
 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
tickNumber = int(0)
done = False
boxOneSymbol = 0
boxTwoSymbol = 0
boxThreeSymbol = 0
boxFourSymbol = 0
boxFiveSymbol = 0
boxSixSymbol = 0
boxSevenSymbol = 0
boxNineSymbol = 0
smallBoxColor = (154, 154, 154)
playerTurn = 0
FPS_CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
#mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
left, middle, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
 

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Roboto', 13)
 

 
while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    is_blue = not is_blue

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 255), pygame.Rect(10, 10, 280, 280))  
        

        #if is_blue: color = (0, 128, 255)
        #else: color = (255, 100, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(30, 120, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(30, 215, 60, 60))
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(120, 215, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(120, 120, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(120, 30, 60, 60))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(215, 215, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(215, 120, 60, 60))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, smallBoxColor, pygame.Rect(215, 30, 60, 60))


        textsurface = font.render('Au joueur 1!', False, (0, 0, 0))
        
        
 
        #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        #if mouse_presses[0]:
            #print("Left Mouse key was clicked")

        left, middle, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
 
        if left:
            print("Left Mouse Key is being pressed")

        pygame.display.update()
        FPS_CLOCK.tick(30)
        tickNumber = (tickNumber) + (1)
        #print(int(tickNumber), 'Ticks')
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Im making a tic-tac-toe game with pygame, and i need to detect when player clicks somewhere, so i found this little piece of code on https://coderslegacy.com/ :

```
       left, middle, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

           if left:
              print("Left Mouse Key is being pressed")
```

to detect left click, but it always detect up to 4 clicks instead of only one, because my tick clock is refreshing 4 times while i click, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use flags and add a condition:

```py
clicked = False

while not done:
    left, middle, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if left and not clicked:
        clicked = True
        print('clicked')
    if not left:
        clicked = False
```

You can also use events since no more `...DOWN` events will be generated while you hold the button:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1:
            print('clicked')
```